# ROS: merge two topics and publish one

Tags: ros, publisher, subscriber

I am trying to get the information out of two different topics and publish it on a new one.

Topic 1 is called `/objecstInfo` which is of a custom msg type `find_object_2d/DetectionInfo`. I need to extract the `filePaths` out of this topic/msg.

```
Header header

# All arrays should have the same size
std_msgs/Int32[] ids
std_msgs/Int32[] widths
std_msgs/Int32[] heights
std_msgs/String[] filePaths
std_msgs/Int32[] inliers
std_msgs/Int32[] outliers
# 3x3 homography matrix: [h11, h12, h13, h21, h22, h23, h31, h32, h33] (h31 = dx and h32 = dy, see QTransform)
std_msgs/Float32MultiArray[] homographies
```

Topic 2 is called `/objectsPose` which is of msg type `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped`. I need to extract the x and y Pose out of this topic.

The topic I want to publish this information is called `/objectsTopic`. I made a custom msg for this called `ObjectTopic.msg` which looks like this:

```
Header header
string objectName
float64 poseX
float64 poseY
```

in `objectName` I want to publish `filePaths` from topic 1 and in `poseX` and `poseY` I want to publish `pose.x` and `pose.y` from topic 2. I found this method [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) but could not implement it successfully in my code. In fact I could not even get the topic published. When I run the node and execute `rostopic list` the topic `/objectsTopic` is not listed.

This is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import rospy
import message_filters
from find_object_2d.msg     import ObjectPose
from find_object_2d.msg     import DetectionInfo
from geometry_msgs.msg      import PoseStamped

def listener():
    info_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/objectsInfo', DetectionInfo)
    pose_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/objectsPose', PoseStamped)

    ts = message_filters.TimeSynchronizer([info_sub, pose_sub], 10)
    ts.registerCallback(callback)
    rospy.spin()

def callback(objectsInfo, objectsPose):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('objectsTopic', ObjectPose, queue_size=10)                       
    msg = ObjectPose()                              
    msg.objectName = objectsInfo.DetectionInfo.filePaths
    msg.poseX = objectsPose.PoseStamped.pose.position.x     
    msg.poseY = objectsPose.PoseStamped.pose.position.y               

    pub.publish(msg)                              
    rospy.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('object_topic', anonymous=True)             
    try:
        listener()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Help would be really appreciated! If there are other ways of solving this problem then using `message_filters` feel free to suggest.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure, I currently have no computer with ROS with me to test it but I would not declare `pub = rospy.Publisher('objectsTopic', ObjectPose, queue_size=10)` inside the function but instead I would create a class. This class initialises a `info_sub` and `pose_sub` class member as well as the `pub`. The `callback` is then a member function which only publishes the topic. I think the problem here is that you put the `pub` into the `callback` as well. This way the publisher goes out of scope as soon as the `callback` function stops and ROS therefore displays this message to you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have solved it by using "ApproximateTime Policy" method from message_filters.  
I changed the ts variable to this: `ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([info_sub, pose_sub], 10)`
I think the problem was that both topics published in different time stamps so I could not get any input for my own topic.